# Is there any way to persist VS Code extensions in VDI?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vdi

Every day when I log into VDI my **vscode extensions** get removed on a daily basis. 
So I need to install them every day. Is there any walk around to keep the extensions with persistence and that I don't have to download/install it again on a daily basis when ever I log in.

Any help would be much appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using a nonpersistent VDI, so you should ask your IT to install the vscode extensions that you need in the image stored in the servers.

Excerpt retrieved [here](https://searchvirtualdesktop.techtarget.com/definition/virtual-desktop-infrastructure-VDI):

> There are two main approaches to VDI: persistent and nonpersistent. Persistent VDI provides each user with his or her own desktop image, which can be customized and saved for future use, much like a traditional physical desktop. **Nonpersistent VDI provides a pool of uniform desktops that users can access when needed. Nonpersistent desktops revert to their original state each time the user logs out.**

Answer (score 0):

Found this on GitHub and it is down near the bottom... https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/17691

Create an environment variable named VSCODE_EXTENSIONS.  Set the path you wish the extensions to be stored.  We used a network share in our implementation to keep extensions persistent in a non-persistent VDI. (e.g VSCODE_EXTENSIONS = \\Server\Share\%USERNAME%\.vscode)

This environment variable must be in place before VSCode launches.  We are utilizing this with VSCode 1.52.1 and it is working for us.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work in my environment. You need to install the extensions using the .vis format, and then copy the extensions from that local profile to a location any user can access. After that, create a GPO that will run this script at every logon and set the scope to your VDI access AD group. The logon GPO is located at **User Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Scripts > Logon > Powershell** This may be a crude way of doing it, but it's working in my environment.

```
#This will not work unless there are extensions on the root of the default user         
#folder. Install Visual Studio Code and its extensions first, then copy the
#entire "\.vscode" folder from the user profile you installed it into and onto      
#the default user profile root folder.

#This script tests to see if the extensions already exist in the root folder of 
#the user logging in using the path described in the below variable.
$vscodeextensions = "$env:USERPROFILE\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools- 
1.13.2"

#This will just allow the script to run.
Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass

If(-not(Test-Path $vscodeextensions)){
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\Default\.vscode\" -Destination "$env:USERPROFILE\" 
-Force -Recurse
}
else{
Write-Host "Extensions already copied"
}
```